# webrtc - signaling server with php or node.js

Tags: php, node.js, streaming, video-streaming, webrtc

I'm trying to build a simple video streaming web application where one user (chatroom owner) broadcasts video from his webcam and the other users (chatroom members) are able to see it in real time

i have done tons of researches on google so i found out that what i need is :

- get the adapter.js file for compatibility ( no clue where to get it )

- get video stream from the webcam

- send it to a server

- have the server send it to certain users

- clients receive that video stream and displays it inside a < video > tag

i was only able to do the first step, the examples i found on the web are clear and simple

for the other steps, all examples i found on the web explains how to do this locally on a single page but i want to do it remotly, even followed the guides in O'reilly WebRTC book

i have no clue what i should write in the server side code or how to send the received video stream ( i have some examples but i didn't understand the code )

i have no clue how the clients will receive that stream ( no examples found for this one, all examples out there send and receive video on the same page )

#### can anyone help, my server side langages is PHP but i can switch to Node.js if that's a must

Comment: With PHP you have a server; you write scripts to run on the server. With node.js you write the server too.

Comment: i know, do you have a working example of the code ?

Comment: *"get video stream from the webcam"* Will require Flash or some other plugin in addition to client side language.  *"clients receive that video stream and displays it inside a < video > tag"* Nope. Impossible. Requires Flash, Silverlight, or some other ActiveX plugin.

Comment: Oh its for mobile (gets around the need for a plugin) and using WebRTC...they have sample code. Probably not easy to fit all the pieces together, but why would you think something this fancy would be easy?

Comment: like i said, i already managed to do that, i'm stuck in transmitting that video to the server

Comment: @developerwjk You have absolutely no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: @user6677 Any particular reason you want to use WebRTC?  And, how many people will be viewing the stream?

Comment: WebRTC seems to be the most convenient way to do it, i don't care about technology i just need it to work

Comment: Is hard to find examples about WebRTC yet. I wanted to do a simple text chat, but only found 2 users examples and no PHP signaling...

Answer (score 4):

Am answering your questions inline

1. You can get adapter.js file from https://github.com/webrtc/adapter/tree/master/release
2. To get video stream from the webcam, use [getUserMedia API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia), see the [demo](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/gum/)
3. To Stream video to viewers, use [PeerConnection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection),

   - WebRTC has no specific signalling defined, you can use any signalling to exchange offer/answer/candidates between publisher and viewer using any server(node/php) in p2p. See official complex [demo](https://appr.tc/) and get the [source](https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc).
   - If you want to stream to multiple viewers, then you need a [media server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC_Gateway), see demos [Janus](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/videoroomtest.html) & [Jitsi](https://meet.jit.si/)

You can find more resources [here](https://webrtc.org/start)

Comment: i already saw these links, they didn't help much that's why i'm askin a question in the first place

Answer (score 4):

So, it seems you ask for help and you have tons of questions.

Regarding local or remotely: there is no difference whether it only works on your computer or at a server. Usually you test things locally on your computer, and then you put it online. You usually do not need to change your code (except settings like URLs) to get it working on a server.

You say you have no idea what you should write at the server code. Well, it is just for signalling, so any two browsers should be able to communicate. Usually it is done with websockets and coded with less than 10 lines of code for node.js; there are plenty of small examples of that, like [here](https://github.com/shanet/WebRTC-Example) . You say your main server language is PHP; that is challenging because PHP can not use websockets without commandline access. If you have regular shared-hosted PHP access, you can use my example at http://github.com/nielsbaloe/webrtc-php which uses ServerSideEvents.

You want to know how clients will receive the stream. Well, the browser takes care of the streams. You only have to take care of the handshakes. So when you have code for two browsers running  (like in my example), it is exactly the same code for more clients, you can extend it so that there is one sender and multiple viewers.